# ASP.NET WebForms PageMethods architecture

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, pagemethods

I just arrived in a new company and I'm now facing different system architectures.

The current one i'm working with, has the following features:

It works as 3 layers, it has:

- DAL
- BLL
- Website

In the asp.net aspx.cs file, there are [WebMethods] functions that are accessed by PageMethods in the clientside.

The question is: Is there any architecture name for this? what are the cons and pros for this kind of system?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

There is no fancy name, its just called 'N-Layered Architecure' or sometimes 'N-Tier'. In your case it is 3 layered, Data Access Layer (DAL), Business Logic Layer (BLL), Presentation Layer (website)

This link can be helpful: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee658109.aspx